# Waiting time when applying for a German passport abroad?

Tags: passports, canada, germany, consulates

I've noticed that there are a fair amount of Germans here. I just applied for my first German passport at the consulate in Vancouver and they told me that it takes around 8-10 weeks to arrive, which seems a bit excessive. For those of you who are Germans living outside of Germany, how long did it take for you to receive your passport? Also, from what consular post did you apply?

Comment: It's a valid question in any case but it does not seem particularly excessive compared to the info that can be found on the web or to what some other countries require. There is also a CYA aspect, nobody will complain if it comes quicker than expected. In my consulate (I am not German), there are signs warning that passport applications can take several months to be processed and that you should apply well in advance, yet I received mine in two weeks.

Comment: Since this relates to living outside of your "home" country, it might perhaps be better off on the [Expats SE site](http://expatriates.stackexchange.com/) rather than here?

Comment: Seems perfectly fine here, while it would be acceptable on Expats too, that doesn't make it off topic on travel.

Comment: However it would be good for the OP to specify which country they're now in...given that it'll likely be slightly different in each of the 190+ countries...

Comment: Applying for your first German passport also suggests that you are probably a dual citizen. Can you identify the country of your dual citizenship as well? It may matter in your discussion out here.

Comment: I'm German but applied for my passport back in Germany. The official waiting time there is 3 weeks. 8 to 10 weeks therefore doesn't surprise me at all (sending the document(s); verifying your case; etc)

Comment: @Stockfisch Seems pretty long. Odd. Is it common to be this long? Is there a way to speed it up in Germany? In India, it's easily possible to get your passport in a week. I was in a hurry once, we got it back in two days. It was a close call though. Turns out we realized that my passport was expired _after_ booking the flights. :/

Comment: @AdityaSomani Within Germany, there is a fast-track procedure (for a fee). Don't know about consulates.

Comment: @AdityaSomani Germans can live elsewhere in the EU with a national ID card (*Personalausweis*). I applied for my first passport abroad without being a dual citizen.

Comment: @Relaxed I've started to consider the EU as one country for all practical purposes. =P

Comment: Cross-post: http://expatriates.stackexchange.com/q/2456

Answer (score 3):

I have applied for a new passport in the German embassy of Kuala Lumpur, Malaysia in 2012 after my current one was full.

It took 28 days for it to arrive. I was not called as they had promised but had to inquire myself. That was during traveling and my registered place of residence was in Germany.

Unlike other countries, Germany does not print passports anywhere but in Berlin. According to wikipedia the process takes 3-6 weeks. Also, while my current passport was still valid I still had to provide a certified copy of my birth certificate, what a useless pain in the ass...